# Reading in existing file in Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.6

Alright, I'm really new to flex.  I have a data file on my computer that I need my flex mobile app to read from.  Is it possible to put this file in a certain location on my computer so that the app will see it when I'm testing(ex-can i put it in a folder that is linked to the applicationstoragedirectory directory)?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just drop it in the source folder, it will automatically be copied into the bin-debug folder (there are a few choice exceptions that you can find in the window->preferences->Flash Builder->File Exclusions) Everything that is copied into the bin-debug would also be packaged into an air or airi file and ultimately deployed next to the bytecode/executable just like it is in the bin-debug in the builder.

You can also make another folder, say "resources" then in the project properties in the flex build path go to source path tab and click add folder button and type "resources".  Then it will treat that and the src folder the same.